# Finding all pairs of common tangents in a curve

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving

My question is kind of an extension of a question asked previously ([Common tangent to a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25892/common-tangent-to-a-curve)) . The difference is that(instead of just one pair) I need to find all pairs of common tangents to a plot.

```
normalizedfplot={{0.01, 0.}, {0.02, -0.0000539749}, {0.03, -0.000101768}, {0.04, \
-0.000147006}, {0.05, -0.000191386}, {0.06, -0.000235889}, {0.07, \
-0.000281142}, {0.08, -0.000327577}, {0.09, -0.000375499}, {0.1, \
-0.000425131}, {0.11, -0.000476637}, {0.12, -0.000530134}, {0.13, \
-0.000585708}, {0.14, -0.000643418}, {0.15, -0.000703296}, {0.16, \
-0.00076536}, {0.17, -0.000829608}, {0.18, -0.000896023}, {0.19, \
-0.000964576}, {0.2, -0.00103522}, {0.21, -0.0011079}, {0.22, \
-0.00118255}, {0.23, -0.00125909}, {0.24, -0.00133741}, {0.25, \
-0.00141742}, {0.26, -0.00149898}, {0.27, -0.00158197}, {0.28, \
-0.00166622}, {0.29, -0.00175156}, {0.3, -0.0018378}, {0.31, \
-0.00192473}, {0.32, -0.00201211}, {0.33, -0.00209968}, {0.34, \
-0.00218713}, {0.35, -0.00227415}, {0.36, -0.00236037}, {0.37, \
-0.00244538}, {0.38, -0.00252871}, {0.39, -0.00260987}, {0.4, \
-0.00268827}, {0.41, -0.00276326}, {0.42, -0.00283413}, {0.43, \
-0.00290008}, {0.44, -0.00296023}, {0.45, -0.00301362}, {0.46, \
-0.00305925}, {0.47, -0.00309612}, {0.48, -0.00312327}, {0.49, \
-0.00313991}, {0.5, -0.00314552}, {0.51, -0.00313991}, {0.52, \
-0.00312327}, {0.53, -0.00309612}, {0.54, -0.00305925}, {0.55, \
-0.00301362}, {0.56, -0.00296023}, {0.57, -0.00290008}, {0.58, \
-0.00283413}, {0.59, -0.00276326}, {0.6, -0.00268827}, {0.61, \
-0.00260987}, {0.62, -0.00252871}, {0.63, -0.00244538}, {0.64, \
-0.00236037}, {0.65, -0.00227415}, {0.66, -0.00218713}, {0.67, \
-0.00209968}, {0.68, -0.00201211}, {0.69, -0.00192473}, {0.7, \
-0.0018378}, {0.71, -0.00175156}, {0.72, -0.00166622}, {0.73, \
-0.00158197}, {0.74, -0.00149898}, {0.75, -0.00141742}, {0.76, \
-0.00133741}, {0.77, -0.00125909}, {0.78, -0.00118255}, {0.79, \
-0.0011079}, {0.8, -0.00103522}, {0.81, -0.000964576}, {0.82, \
-0.000896023}, {0.83, -0.000829608}, {0.84, -0.00076536}, {0.85, \
-0.000703296}, {0.86, -0.000643418}, {0.87, -0.000585708}, {0.88, \
-0.000530134}, {0.89, -0.000476637}, {0.9, -0.000425131}, {0.91, \
-0.000375499}, {0.92, -0.000327577}, {0.93, -0.000281142}, {0.94, \
-0.000235889}, {0.95, -0.000191386}, {0.96, -0.000147006}, {0.97, \
-0.000101768}, {0.98, -0.0000539749}, {0.99, 0.}}
```

The above list looks like this.

[image]

Now when I use the code used in the solution to the previous problem, it gives me only one solution

```
fo = Interpolation[normalizedfplot, Method -> "Spline"];
 boundary = FindRoot[{y1==fo[x1],y2==fo[x2], fo'[x1]==fo'[x2], fo'[x1]==(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)},
  {x1,0.01},{x2,0.5},{y1,-0.025},{y2,-0.0275}]
```

The solution is :

```
{x1 -> 0.00124073, x2 -> 0.419065, y1 -> 0.000055584, 
 y2 -> -0.0028277}
```

The above is kind of expected  since FindRoot gives us only one root depending on the initial guesses. What I need is a general code that will give me all possible pairs in any kind of lists. Using NSolve did not help. I can write a code to do this. However, I believe there must be an elegant way of doing this using Mathematica's functions.

Comment: Crossposted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1166192

Comment: Please link to Community here when you are posting here and there (and vice-versa).