# Find a line tangent to two points on a curve

Tags: manipulate

How can I use Mathematica to find the line tangent to two points on a curve?

For the curve defined by `Gibbs[x_]`, sometimes I can draw a tangent line connecting two points.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{a, b, r, Gibbs},
  a = 7500; b = 1000; r = 8.314;
  Gibbs[x_] := 
   x*(1 - x)*(a + b*(1 - 2*x)) + r*t*(x*Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x])
  ],
 Control[{{t, 398, "temperature (K)"}, 273, 523, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled" }]]
```

The temperature is 398 K for the picture shown.

[image]

Comment: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25892/common-tangent-to-a-curve) could help

Answer (score 1):

Basic definitions

```
a = 7500;
b = 1000;
r = 8.314;
Gibbs[x_, t_] := 
  x*(1 - x)*(a + b*(1 - 2*x)) + r*t*(x*Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x]);
DGibbs[x_, t_] := 
  Evaluate[D[
    x*(1 - x)*(a + b*(1 - 2*x)) + r*t*(x*Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x]),
     x]];
```

We are looking for a linear function of the form $f[x_] :=slope x + offset`and two x-values`x1`and`x2` such that

```
{
DGibbs[x1, 398] == slope, 
DGibbs[x2, 398] == slope, 
Gibbs[x1, 398] == slope x1 + offset, 
Gibbs[x2, 398] == slope x2 + offset
}
```

hold all true. We write down a function `F` in the variables `{x1,x2,slope,offset}` that has roots precisely when these conditions are fulfilled and aplly `FindRoot` to it:

```
Quiet[Block[{X},
   F[X_?VectorQ] := Evaluate[N[{
        DGibbs[X[[1]], 398] - X[[3]],
        DGibbs[X[[2]], 398] - X[[3]],
        X[[3]] X[[1]] + X[[4]] - Gibbs[X[[1]], 398],
        X[[3]] X[[2]] + X[[4]] - Gibbs[X[[2]], 398]
        }]];

   ]];
{x1, x2, slope, offset} = FindRoot[F, {{{0.1, 0.8, -2., -301}}}][[1]]
Plot[{Gibbs[x, 398], slope x + offset}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is "Gibbs" in the last bit of code, Gibbs[x,t]? Will this work for all temperatures, not just 398 K?

Comment: I put the `t`-dependence into the function `Gibbs`. If you change the `398` in the definition of `F` to other values, this might also work...